# Conditionally return ForwardRefExoticComponent and FunctionalComponent

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have created a wrapper on MUI TextField component i.e. `TextFieldWrapper` with custom stylings and validations. It is being in the app in many places.

The problem with this is it cannot be used with MUI `Tooltip` because for that `ref` needs to be forwarded.

I cannot wrap the `TextFieldWrapper` with `React.forwardRef()` because wrapping it with `forwardRef` will change its return type and it breaks at other places.

So, currently, I have 2 `TextField` components i.e. `TextFieldWrapper` and `TooltipTextField`.

**The issue is, as I said earlier, the `TextField` has some stylings and validations applied to it and that is being duplicated in both `TextFieldWrapper` and `TooltipTextField` if I use separate components as shown below.**

Is there a workaround for this or it could be improved in some way? I mean if I could combine these 2 (`TextFieldWrapper` and `TooltipTextField`) into one functional component and return it conditionally or in some way?

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/basictooltip-material-demo-forked-v8lrb4?file=/demo.tsx:0-799

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Tooltip, TextField, TextFieldProps } from "@mui/material";

// Return type is React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<Pick<TextFieldProps> & React.RefAttributes<...>>
const TooltipTextField = React.forwardRef(
  (
    props: TextFieldProps,
    ref: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>
  ): React.ReactElement => {
    return <TextField ref={ref} {...props} />;
  }
);

// Return type is React.React.ReactElement
const TextFieldWrapper = (props: TextFieldProps): React.ReactElement => {
  return <TextField {...props} />;
};

export default function BasicTooltip() {
  return (
    <>
      <Tooltip title="Tooltip Textfield">
        <TooltipTextField value="Tooltip TextField" />
      </Tooltip>

      <TextFieldWrapper value="General TextField" />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways you can do.

1. Using assertion `as` keyword and specify the type of the component you have.

```js
const TooltipTextField = React.forwardRef(
  (props: TextFieldProps, ref: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    return <TextField ref={ref} {...props} />;
  }
) as React.FC<TextFieldProps>;
```

2. Wrap the component with another MUI component like `Box`. This will change the target component to `Box` and it will do what is needed for `Tooltip`.

```js
<Tooltip title="Tooltip Textfield">
  <Box sx={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
    <GeneralTextField value="General TextField" />
  </Box>
</Tooltip>
```

3. Create a component combining `Tooltip` and `TextField` (what you mentioned).

```js
const TextFieldWithTooltip = ({ tooltipProps, ...rest }: TextFieldProps & { tooltipProps?: TooltipProps }): React.ReactElement => {
  return (
    <Tooltip {...tooltipProps} title={tooltipProps?.title || ''}>
      <TextField {...rest} />
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

Please take a look at tooltip props at https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tooltip/#props

And notice that,

- If you pass empty string for title wont show the tooltip.
- You also can use props like `disableHoverListener` which prevents showing the tooltip, etc.

I also provided a [demo on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/72228860-forwardref-hv8sm5?file=/demo.tsx) which may be helpful. Follow `FIXME` tags in the code ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, Adel. Is it correct to typecast `React.ForwardRefExoticComponent` to `React.FC`? `React.FC` is not the parent of `React.ForwardRefExoticComponent`so can we really typecast this?

Comment: @newbie It's kind of a trick :))

Comment: @newbie But I personally prefer the last one: creating a component combining Tooltip and TextField

Comment: Yeah, it is a workaround but can't be a proper solution :D But your solutions are amazing. Just one minor help, the last solution also gives some warning. Can you please check the CodeSandbox line 49?

Comment: @newbie Yes :) children prop is required, ha ha, I fixed it, we no longer need children!